# ActiveRecordNotFound Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When a user sing-in user can be accesible to delete his own account. But after delete a user(redirected root url) I'm getting ActiveRecordNotFound error. It says couldn't find user id = 1. What would have cost it this error?

Comment: Do you sign out that user? Do you clear you session? Are you using some gem to manage user?

Comment: Before delete user you mean? Otherwise sign in or sign out work well.

Comment: Before you delete you user, do you sign him out ?

Comment: No I don't. Well probably that's the missing part. Thanks. I will try this out.

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your session and sign out user you are trying to delete, otherwise it will try to access it and obviously it doesn't exists.